# Javascript regexp does not work

Tags: javascript, regex

Test string is "page-42440233_45778105"
pattern "(page-\d+_\d+)"

Online tester(http://www.regexr.com/) successfuly finded mathc,but in browser js result is null. Why?

```
var re = new RegExp("(page-\d+_\d+)", "gim");
var r_array = message.match(re);
console.log(r_array);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape `\` if you use string literal:

```
var message = "page-42440233_45778105";
var re = new RegExp("(page-\\d+_\\d+)", "gim");
var r_array = message.match(re);
console.log(r_array);
// => ["page-42440233_45778105"]
```

More preferably, use regular expression literal:

```
var re = /(page-\d+_\d+)/gim;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be a better pattern

```
var re = /^page-\d+_\d+$/i;
```

It also matches the beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string

---

```
message.match(re);
//=> ["page-42440233_45778105"]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a string literal, you must escape the `\` :

```
var re = new RegExp("(page-\\d+_\\d+)", "gim");
```

A better solution here would be to use a regex literal :

```
var re = /(page-\d+_\d+)/gim
```

Don't use the RegExp constructor if the regular expression is constant, regex literals are much more convenient.